# SQL - Where the value in column 1, row 1 is not the same as column 2, row 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to return data wherein the employee who created the ticket is not the same as the employee who updated it.

This is what the data looks like:

```
Tickets   |   Created_by   | Updated_by
Tick-1    |   John         | John
Tick-2    |   Mike         | Mike
Tick-3    |   Carl         | Amir
Tick-4    |   Amir         | Carl
```

Expected Output:

```
Tickets   |   Created_by   | Updated_by
Tick-3    |   Carl         | Amir
Tick-4    |   Amir         | Carl
```

`Tick1` & `Tick2` were removed because the Row value in *Created_by* and *Updated_by* are the same.

I have a workaround that looks something like this:

```
SELECT Tickets, Created_by, Updated_by
FROM table
WHERE Created_by = 'John' AND Updated_by != 'John'
```

But the issue is I have to do it 1 by 1 per each person and we have hundreds of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you try something like this

```
SELECT Tickets, Created_by, Updated_by
FROM table
WHERE Created_by <> Updated_by
```

Comment: @Jonathan Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Tickets, Created_by, Updated_by 
From TABLENAME
Where Created_by != Updated_by
```

Try this, hope this help you